# Is it possible to set a volume label on a bind mount

Tags: mount

I'm playing around with using bind mounts in order to fake presence of USB removable storage devices in unit test code.

```
mkdir /tmp/fake_USB_drive

<set up some fake content>

mkdir /media/$USER/fake_USB_drive
sudo mount --bind /tmp/fake_USB_drive /media/$USER/fake_USB_drive
```

I've got some application code to test that relates to a piece of electronics equipment that connects over USB using mass storage device profile, presenting a custom/known volume label that I query to distinguish it from a generic mass storage device.

I would like to be able to fake this label on my bind mount.

What I've tried:

**e2label**, which not surprisingly doesn't work, as it expects a device argument

Answer (score 1):

Looks as though if I use a loop device (https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man4/loop.4.html) rather than a bind mount to simulate the USB mass storage device, I can successfully use **e2label** to set a volume label.